# Discrepancies in Event Parameters and Dates Ranges in GA4 to Google BigQuery Export

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I'm working with Google Analytics 4 (GA4) linked to Google BigQuery and facing two specific issues:

1. **Number of Event Parameters:** Normally, in GA4 to BigQuery exports, I see about 32 parameters or events in the exported tables. However, in my case, there are only 18. I expected to see a similar number of parameters as commonly noted in documentation and other references. Is this a normal variation, or might there be an issue with the export process?

[image]

2. **Date Range Discrepancies:** When conducting queries, I'm not retrieving the full date range of data since the GA4 link to BigQuery was established in June 2023. I expected to see all the data from the start of the link but am finding gaps in the date ranges.

What I've Tried:

- Rechecking the GA4 to BigQuery linkage to ensure it was set up correctly.

My concerns are whether GA4 is exporting fewer events than it should or if there's a misconfiguration on my end.

Answer (score 0):

No, 18 is the number of a shared table that was created for you. This means that you have exported tables from GA4 for 18 days, but there might be some days missing due to a lack of events or disconnection. Each shared table has a suffix that indicates the date of the events captured, for example, events_20240105 for January 5th.

Comment: Thank you, Ali. Yup. That's what I thought. Problem is that my connection was made on january 2023, and it seems pretty weird to me that I only have 18 days? Am I doing something wrong? Is it because it is a free tier?

Comment: free tier only keeps your data for 60 days. there is no other consideration related to your issue.